# How do I seed a database in Mac OS X application

Tags: database, swift, sqlite, seed

I want to add a sqlite database stored in the application bundle to the application data storage file path in Mac OS X, how do I do that using Apple's new Swift programming language?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out so I thought I'd post it hear for others to use.

Seed DB to Mac OS X Application with Swift from Application Bundle:

Create a function to handle checking if the database already exists or not, then call if from the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, "DBName" is the name of your database:

```
func openDB()
{

    let storePath = applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(“DBName.sqlite").path
    let dataPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(“DBName", ofType: "sqlite")
    //let testPath = storePath.path
    //let testPath2 = storePath
    if !NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(storePath!)
    {
        do
        {
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(dataPath!, toPath: storePath!)
        } // end do
        catch
        {
            NSLog("Error copying database file")
        } // end catch
    } // end if
} // end openDB
```

I call it in the `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` so it only gets called once

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
```

The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.

```
    // Create the coordinator and store
    self.openDB()
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let storeURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent(storeFilename)
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    do
    {
        //try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil)
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
            NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true])
    }
    catch
    {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: domainName, code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()
```

Comment: Wow, you found the answer to you question fast!